# How to create DLL in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-to-c#

I am using VB.NET 2008, and I want to make a DLL that will be used in a C# project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build your class library in Visual Studio, it will generate the DLL for you and place it in the bin directory.

```
YourProject/bin/Debug/YourProject.dll
YourProject/bin/Release/YourProject.dll
```

It will be placed in the folder that represents your build-mode (Debug / Release), which you can normally switch in your toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `File > New Project` and select `Visual Basic`, `Class Library` as the project type.
Enter your solution name and directory, and click on `OK`.
Voila!

Once you code your library and build it, you can go add it to your references in your C# project.

Answer (score 0):

Just select a `Class library` as the project type.